# Why does QCOMPARE(QString("1"), "1") cause a linker error?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, linker-errors

I'm exploring Qt's unit test framework, and I noticed an odd thing - considering that QString already implements the equality operator for `const char *`, I would have expected `QCOMPARE(QString("1"), "1")` to just work, but instead it causes a linker error:

```
tst_untitled14test.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl QTest::qCompare<class QString,char const [2]>(class QString const &,char const (&)[2],char const *,char const *,char const *,int)" (??$qCompare@VQString@@$$BY01$$CBD@QTest@@YA_NABVQString@@AAY01$$CBDPBD22H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall Untitled14Test::testCase1(void)" (?testCase1@Untitled14Test@@AAEXXZ)
```

Example code:

```
QVERIFY(QString("1") == "1");         // This works.
QCOMPARE(QString("1"), QString("1")); // This works.
// QCOMPARE(QString("1"), "1");       // Causes a linker error!
```

Why is that? Doesn't `QCOMPARE` use the equality operator of the 2 terms?

**Edit:** Since it was asked in the comments, the project is created by Qt Creator's unit test wizard (File->New Project->Other Project->Qt Unit Test), so of course it has been set up properly, and `QT += testlib` is included.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtest.html#QCOMPARE)

> QCOMPARE is very strict on the data types. Both actual and expected
>   have to be of the same type, otherwise the test won't compile. This
>   prohibits unspecified behavior from being introduced; that is behavior
>   that usually occurs when the compiler implicitly casts the argument.

In source code `QCOMPARE` looks like

```
#define QCOMPARE(actual, expected) \
do {\
    if (!QTest::qCompare(actual, expected, #actual, #expected, __FILE__, __LINE__))\
        return;\
} while (0)

template <typename T>
inline bool qCompare(T const &t1, T const &t2, const char *actual, const char *expected,
                        const char *file, int line)
{
    return compare_helper(t1 == t2, "Compared values are not the same",
                              toString(t1), toString(t2), actual, expected, file, line);
}
```

It is a template which requires first and second argument to be of the same type.